# IE-11 Popup issue

Tags: asp.net, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

When I am click on logoff hyperlink in my application, it returns me a popup.

There is a normal code of asp.net which redirect to logoff page and clear session.!

Popup message is: "Do you want to allow this website to open an app on your computer?"

[Click here to see popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRM5J.png)

I do not want this popup.

For this, I have tried to change few settings of IE, but it doesn't work for me.

It will be Appreciate if anyone can suggest the cause of the issue and possible resolution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your actual problem? You're getting a wrong pop-up or you should not get a pop-up at all? Please show the code behind the link.

Comment: @Teemu, updated above problem.

and on code behind I just clear the sesion, and one Iframe is on page, so I just set src for that iframe.

Comment: Setting `src` for an `iframe` doesn't open pop-ups, somewhere in the loaded documents something tries to run an executable.